# How to "Evaluate Formula" in cell in Excel using VBA - e.g. Show working

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be able to "show my working" in excel. So when I print the sheet for clients all the work can be checked without having the original spreadsheet. I'm sort of trying to replicate the "Evaluate Formula" feature of excel, but within the cell. I can do it manually, but it's really time consuming as I have a lot of formula.

So if I have this in a cell

```
=(C2*C3)+C4
```

I want to be able to use VBA magic to turn it into this

```
="("&TEXT(C2,"0.00")&" x "&TEXT(C3,"0.00")&" ) + "&TEXT(C4,"0.00")
```

so the result looks like this

```
(50.22 x 2.11 ) + 3.22
```

I can convert the math's signs (brackets, multiply, etc) in VBA. But I don't know how to recognize the cell references, so that I can do the text conversion part (I can't leave the formula without the text function - the decimal places are too long). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Why not parse =(C2*C3)+C4? Insert "(", take the value of cell C2, translate "*" to "X", take the value of cell C3, add ")" etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will reformat the selected cells and put the result in the cell 1 column to the right.

```
Sub ReformatForumla()
    Dim prec As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim frm As String
    Dim cellRef As String
    Dim loopRng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim stored() As Variant
    Dim sorted As Variant
    
    For Each loopRng In Selection
        frm = Replace(loopRng.Formula, "$", "")
        frm = "=""" & frm & """"
        Set prec = loopRng.Precedents
        i = 1
        ReDim stored(prec.Cells.Count, 2)
        For Each rng In prec
            stored(i, 1) = rng.Address
            stored(i, 2) = Len(rng.Address)
            i = i + 1
        Next rng
        sorted = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sort(stored, 2, -1)
        For i = 1 To prec.Cells.Count
            cellRef = Replace(sorted(i, 2), "$", "")
            frm = Replace(frm, cellRef, """ & TEXT(" & Application.ConvertFormula(cellRef, xlA1, xlA1, xlAbsolute) & ",""0.00"") & """)
        Next i
        frm = Replace(frm, "+", " + ")
        frm = Replace(frm, "-", " - ")
        frm = Replace(frm, "*", " x ")
        frm = Replace(frm, "/", " / ")
        loopRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = frm
    Next loopRng
End Sub
```

Comment: If a formula refers to both C1 and C10, this will replace the C1 part in both, botching the C10 and turning it into `TEXT(C1)0`.

Comment: I don't see how that edit helps. Excel does not reorder cells in `Precedents`. If the formula is `=C1+C10`, then the first `rng` in your `For Each` loop will be C1 and the second C10, so your approach with the reversed `Step - 1` loop will work. If, however, the formula is `=C10+C1`, the first `rng` is C10 and the second is C1, so it will break.

Comment: Keeping me on my toes.  Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Sorted cell references in descending order by length.  Since the longer ones are processed first, there should be no issues with substrings.  I am not sure why but `WorksheetFunction.Sort` seems to shift everything over 1 column.

Comment: That is probably because your `stored` has three columns (0 to 2).

Comment: THANK YOU. This does what I need it to do. The only small issue is that if you have ranges in your formula [e.g. min(A2:A5] it will show the two values rather than the range. But I don't have many of them. And it works if they are comma separated [e.g. min(A2,A3,A4,A5].